# how to draw a transparent combobox?

Tags: mfc, combobox

I have two Cedit and one CCombobox.

you can see the under code, I set the text color to yellow.

then I use a transparent text background, also a transparent background.

It works perfectly fine for Cedit (I don't care the change when I type something in it).

But I notice that the `pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);` do nothing to my CCombobox.

I really don't want to subclass CComboBox to accomplish the transparent background.

or do I need to use drawitem???

```
HBRUSH CValueInputDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)  
{  
    HBRUSH hBrush = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);  
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT)  
    {  
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);  
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 255, 0));  
        hBrush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);  
    }  
    return hBrush;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're gonna be able to get a good result without subclassing or doing some more work. Transparent controls in MFC are not an easy thing.

Anyway, if you want to get the transparent background on the drop-down list of the combo you need to use CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX instead of CTLCOLOR_EDIT. And CTLCOLOR_BTN for the drow-down button.

Comment: the combobox's editbox. It is still the background color I give it!